# High voltage power thermal fuse for DC

Tags: dc, high-voltage, circuit-protection, high-current, thermal-cutoff

I am looking for ways to break a high voltage DC power line when an overheating scenario occurs. Preferably I would like to do so using a thermal fuse but can’t find any thermal fuses rated for high power and voltage DC. Does this not exist? Is it too hard to stop the arcing? Or is it too hard to find a material that can handle high power and still melt at increased temperatures?

I want a thermal fuse that can handle peaks of 1000VDC and peak currents of 30A roughly. The breaking temperature is less important since I can adjusted the proximity to the heat source.

If this does not exist what are my options? A low voltage thermal fuse triggering a pyro-fuse or similar? Size of component (and to a lesser extent cost) is important!

Comment: Check similar to this one. It is rated as 20A.
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/1000V-20A-Fuse-Link-New-Original_1600256263486.html

Comment: Call me paranoid, but I wouldn't trust a high voltage/high power circuit's safety to an Alibaba part.  I am seeing a fuse on Digikey rated for 1kVDC @ 30A for what seems like a reasonable price however.

Comment: Is the high voltage DC power line supplied from AC power?

Comment: I do not trust a fuse from alibaba. I could only find thermal fuses/cutoffs with Max 60 VDC on digikey. Unfourtunately the DC power is not supplied from AC otherwise this would have been a Mich simpler problem!

Answer (score 1):

They do exist but are [expensive.](https://ep-ca.mersen.com/sites/mersen_ca/files/DS-Semiconductor-Protection-Cylindrical-Fuses-Protistor-Size-20x127-gR-1000VDC-to-1500VDC-EN.pdf)  Due to the inertia of plasma during the fusing process the suppression of arcs requires a special arc suppression material inside a long tube such as solid silica dioxide.

Potential power in the plasma arc could start upwards of 30 kW, so it must react very fast.

[image]

Comment: This looks like it is a regular fuse not a thermal fuse/cutoff? I will not have an overcurrent when overheating only fire hazard!

Comment: where are  your load specs for a temperature-controlled thermal "switch".   Fuses are current rated since current also causes heat then fuses the link and DC inductive creates a long arc. How much inductive energy is stored when switching in the DC current loop also matters,  This is NOT a simple DC FUSE but rather a snubber and something else

Comment: It is not  240Vac Thermal switch you want because like Triacs zero crossing current extinguishes the arc.  "Thermal fuses" mean something else and not what you expect

Comment: It might be a high energy switch with  long solenoid throw controlled by some sensor

Comment: Or it could be a >1kV rated FET or IGBT controlled by a thermal sensor.  But without all your expectations or specs from you , it's hard to tell

Comment: "A thermal cutoff is an electrical safety device (either a thermal fuse or thermal switch) that interrupts electric current when heated to a specific temperature. These devices may be for one-time use (a thermal fuse), or may be reset manually or automatically (a thermal switch)." - This is what I want, load case is as I presented in my question 1000VDC and 30A. IGBT/FET is an alternative but not preferable.

Comment: Sorry but you never asked for a "Thermal cutoff" and the two examples operate quite differently. You still failed to define what I requested in the stored energy or the real power and impedance at cutoff. No more comments here.  IGBT's are also rated for this but the SOA confines how both simultaneously with impedance time constants and thus time duration and thus quench energy

Comment: Wait I am still confused! Isn't a thermal fuse just a variant of a thermal cutoff? I don't know the impedance at cutoff or real power of the top of my head! However right now I am using a SiC MOSFET to turn it off right now so this is definitely possible but I would like to know if there are thermal cutoffs/fuses rated for such large DC voltages?

Comment: Thermal fuses trip mostly by conduction current reaching the melting point and thermal switches trip mostly by ambient temperature using spring loaded bimetallic contacts. So yes cutoff has 2 examples but operate differently and you aren't looking for a current fuse

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a thermal function to disconnect high power. A combination of a standard thermal switch that can fire a thyristor to short the main supply and open a fast fuse could be an option. Also a power breaker with tripping coil connected to a standard thermal fuse could work, not cheap, but can be used many times.

Comment: In my application a power breaker will mist likely be too big, too costly and it serves no purpose to be usable several times since an overheat can only happen of the regular circuit malfunctions.

Yes I have considered the thermal switch which causes a short. It seems like this is the most plausible solution if no direct thermal fuses are usable.